# Run a process and return its PID (as CHP.EXE) for a batch file

Tags: batch, pid

I'm looking for something like chp.exe, it can runs a command and returns its pid.
I can not use CHP.EXE because it seems to be reported as infected file in some antiviruses.

Thanks

Comment: You can run the program and parse the output of `tasklist`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Wmic process where (Name like '%CHP%') get caption, name, commandline, ProcessId | more
```

real sample:

```
Wmic process where (Name like '%ie%') get caption, name, commandline, ProcessId | more
```

Output:

[image: ProcessId where like name Wmic Far manager]

```
Wmic process get ProcessId
```

extract only the processId into a variable from query output:

ProcID.cmd:

```
@ECHO OFF                                                                              
FOR /F %%T IN ('Wmic process where^(Name^="explorer.exe"^)get ProcessId^|more +1') DO (
SET /A ProcessId=%%T) &GOTO SkipLine                                                   
:SkipLine                                                                              
echo ProcessId = %ProcessId%
```

Output:

```
ProcessId = 2372
```

Comment: any suggestion to extract only the processId into a variable from query output?

Comment: @Tobia see again

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty straightforward to do in PowerShell. `Start-Process notepad.exe -PassThru` will start Notepad and return:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName                                                                                                                              
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------                                                                                                                              
     45       6     1672       4240    61     0.02   9212 notepad
```

From there you could use it like an object by storing the output (`$notepad = Start-process notepad.exe -PassThru` and then `$notepad.ID`) and finish whatever scripting you were doing with it.

Getting it back to a batch script (if absolutely necessary) is a little tricky. If you're absolutely stuck on using a batch file, it would probably be easiest to write a PowerShell script that writes the relevant information to a file or registry key, call the PowerShell script from the batch file, and then read the file or reg key later in the batch script.

If you don't want to touch PowerShell at all then you'll have to resort to WMIC or tasklist to find the process after creating it.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the program and then issue this command, substituting `firefox.exe` with the process name you want:

```
for /f "tokens=2" %a in ('tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq firefox.exe"') do @if not [%a]==[No] @echo %a
```

It will output solely the **pid**. In my case, the output is `5540`. If the program is not running, no output will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Another way :: You can create a batch file and put following code to batch file. Its first run netstat command to get processId for port 9797. And then set it into a variable.

```
@ECHO OFF                                                                              
FOR /F "tokens=5" %%T IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr "9797" ') DO (
SET /A ProcessId=%%T) &GOTO SkipLine                                                   
:SkipLine                                                                              
echo ProcessId = %ProcessId%
PAUSE
```

Comment: Please *explain* what this is doing.